# GeoServer legend in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, geoserver, wms, legend

I have created a WMS service showing a simple polygon layer with three categories which I use for styling.

- In QGIS I can simply expand/click the layer in Layers panel and see the legend.
- In ArcMap the only option is to "Add WMS legend to map" which add a graphic to the map.

Is there some way to make ArcMap show the legend like QGIS does, in the table of contents/layers panel?

[image]

Comment: Not specific to GeoServer software, it's any WMS

Comment: looks like a bug - you'll need to ask ESRI to fix it, after all that's what they get paid the big bucks for.

Comment: I think this would be regarded by ESRI as a feature rather than a bug.  The table of contents is for managing layers, not for viewing legends.  The only reason is shows symbology there is so that you can manage the symbology.  You cannot manage the symbology of a WMS layer.

Comment: @SonofaBeach you can manage the symbology of a WMS that supports SLD requests